# Right way to do TCP connection between python and Qt?

Tags: python, qt, sockets, tcp

I want to connect two programs via TCP. My main program is written with Qt and needs to talk to another program written in Python. I think about using TCP sockets and Google's protobuf to exchange the messages. In Qt, I use a QTcpSocket that accepts the connection and reads from the stream, as soon as its readyRead-Signal is triggered. In python, I also use a tcp-socket and send messages.

This works very well, as long as no side is killed. Currently, the python-side is sending messages to the C++ side. (`socket.send(str(id)+"\ņ")`) After every send, I check for exceptions (connection reset by peer, broken pipe, ...) to see if the message was received. 
If I kill the C++ program, the next message send from the python client triggers no exception, but is obviously not received. The next message triggers the exception, but the last message is lost.

After a bit of experimenting, I found that sending an empty message (`socket.send("\n")`) after each message solves the problem. I do now

```
try:
  s.send(str(id)+"\n");
  s.send("\n")
  sleep(0.5)
except socket.error,v: 
   print "FAILed to send",id,v[0],v[1]
```

and receive the exception as soon as the C++-Peer is killed (calling `s.send(str(id)+"\n\n")` however does not help).

Finally, my question is: Is this a reliable way to check if my message was received? 
I don't want to switch to UDP as I don't want to implement my own ACK-messages for each message.

This is my first time I use sockets with python and C++ and can't really explain why my approach works, so I'm a bit uncomfortable using it.

Can someone tell me a a bit more? I guess that the python socket expects an ACK for the first `send(int(id)+"\n")` after sending the `send("\n")` and then realizes that the pipe is broken. Is this correct?

Comment: The only way to reliably find out if the other end of a connection was closed in a nice way, is to *read* from the connection. Otherwise you end up with hacks like yours.

Comment: Is using a light wrapper around the TCP a problem? http://zeromq.org/ is basically TCP, but on steroids :) so you won't have to take care about low level details. It also has a C++ and Python libs.

Comment: The C++-Side currently does not send anything. I just added a settimeout(0.01) before a s.recv(1024). I now get a socket.timeout as long as the connection is valid. If the C++-peer was terminated, recv returns zero byte (but does not timeout). So I guess I could place this right after I send a message and if I get the zero-byte message, I probably have lost the last message and can resend it after the connection is established again. Is this a cleaner solution?          @Viktor: I'll have a look at zeromq, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

When a TCP connection is broken by the remote peer, your TCP socket will become ready-for-read, and then when you try to recv() from it, recv() will return 0.

Of course if your sending program is only calling send() (the way your Python program is), then it won't notice what's going on with the socket's recv-side, and you end up with the problem you described.

On the other hand, you don't want to just blindly call recv() either, because if recv() is called and the remote peer hasn't sent any data, recv() will block waiting for data and unless the remote peer ever actually sends some, you'll have a deadlock.

The simplest way to deal with that is to use select() to multiplex your I/O, so that your Python script can know when it's appropriate to call send() and/or recv().  Something like this:

```
import socket
import select

[...]
while 1:
   socketsToReadFrom = [s]
   if (you_still_have_more_data_to_send):
       socketsToWriteTo = [s]
   else:
       socketsToWriteTo = None

   # This select() call will block until there's something to do
   socketsReadForRead, socketsReadyForWrite, junk = select.select(socketsToReadFrom, socketsToWriteTo, None)

   if (s in socketsToReadFrom):
      readBytes = s.recv(1024)
      if (len(readBytes) > 0): 
         print "Read %i bytes from remote peer!" % readBytes
      else:
         print "Remote peer closed the TCP Connection!!"
         break

   if ((socketsToWriteTo != None) and (s in socketsToWriteTo)):
      s.send(some_more_data)
```

As far as verifying whether your message was received, that's a bit tricky since TCP (and the network stack) do a fair amount of pipelining/buffering.  In particular, a successful return from send() only tells you that your data has been handed off to your local TCP stack's outgoing-data buffer; it doesn't mean that the data has arrived at the remote peer already.  If you really want a "receipt" that the remote peer has already processed the data, you'll have to have the remote peer send back some kind of acknowledgement.  Note that under TCP that level of sophistication is often unnecessary though, since barring a network or hardware failure (or the remote peer closing the TCP connection), you can be fairly sure that the TCP stack will get your data there eventually; e.g. if a packet got dropped, the TCP stack will resend it automatically.  Data loss will only occur if the network connectivity stops working for an extended period (e.g. several minutes), at which point the TCP stack will give up and close the TCP connection.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried to call recv with a timeout (last comment above) and if the timeout was reached I assumed the connection to be still valid. I finally chose to implement the ACK by just adding a message-ID that will be returned by the receiving end. I think this is a very safe way and I don't rely on features of TCP (as the zero Byte Message) that I don't fully understand yet.

Comment: AFAIK there is no such thing as a zero byte message in TCP.  recv() returning zero means the TCP connection has closed; no more, no less.

Comment: With "zero Byte Message" I tried to refer to this message that contains zero Bytes. So no bytes and not "0000"-Byte.

Comment: if (len(readBytes)==0) then the TCP connection has been closed.